# Python code to download list of csv files from Azure Blob Storage using SAS token

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to to download a list of csv files from an `Azure Blob Storage` using a shared `SAS token`, but I am getting all sorts of errors.

I tried looking this up and tried multiple code samples from contributors on Slackoverflow and Azure documentation. here is the final state of the code sample I constructed from those sources! It tries to download the list of csv files in a pooled manner (blob storage contains 200 csv files):

NB: I left commented code snippets to show different approaches I tried testing. sorry if they are confusing!

```
from itertools import tee
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings, ContainerClient
#from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

STORAGEACCOUNTURL = "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net"
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = "sv=2020-08-04&si=blobpolicyXYZ&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
CONTAINERNAME = "mycontainer"
##BLOBNAME = "??"

sas_url = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydir?sv=2020-08-04&si=blobpolicyXYZ&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
LOCAL_BLOB_PATH = "./downloads"

class AzureBlobFileDownloader:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Intializing AzureBlobFileDownloader")

        # Initialize the connection to Azure storage account
        self.blob_service_client_instance = ContainerClient.from_container_url #BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url) #BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
        #self.blob_client_instance = self.blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME)
        #self.blob_service_client =  BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(MY_CONNECTION_STRING)
        #self.my_container = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(MY_BLOB_CONTAINER)
        
        #self.blob_service_client = BlockBlobService("storage_account",sas_token="?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-04-24T10:01:58Z&st=2019-04-23T02:01:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxx")
        #self.my_container = self.blob_service_client.get_blob_to_path("container_name","blob_name","local_file_path")

        
    def save_blob(self,file_name,file_content):
        # Get full path to the file
        download_file_path = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, file_name)

        # for nested blobs, create local path as well!
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(download_file_path), exist_ok=True)
        
        with open(download_file_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(file_content)
    
    def download_all_blobs_in_container(self):
        # get a list of blobs
        my_blobs = self.blob_service_client_instance.get_block_list() #list_blobs() #self.blob_client_instance.list_blobs() download_blob() #
        print(my_blobs)

        #iterate through the iterable object for testing purposes, maybe wrong approach!
        result, result_backup = tee(my_blobs)
        print("**first iterate**")
        for i, r in enumerate(result):
            print(r)
        
        #start downloading my_blobs
        result = self.run(my_blobs)
        print(result)

    def run(self,blobs):
        # Download 3 files at a time!
        with ThreadPool(processes=int(3)) as pool:
            return pool.map(self.save_blob_locally, blobs)

    def save_blob_locally(self,blob):
        file_name = blob.name
        print(file_name)
        bytes = self.blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME,blob).download_blob().readall()

        # Get full path to the file
        download_file_path = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, file_name)
        # for nested blobs, create local path as well!
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(download_file_path), exist_ok=True)

        with open(download_file_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(bytes)
        return file_name

# Initialize class and download files
azure_blob_file_downloader = AzureBlobFileDownloader()
azure_blob_file_downloader.download_all_blobs_in_container()
```

could someone help me get to achieve this task in python:

- get a list of all files in the blob storage, those files names are prefixed with `part-`
- download them to a folder locally

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could someone help me get to achieve this task in python:
>
> - get a list of all files in the blob storage, those files names are prefixed with part-

To List all the blobs whose prefix is "part-" you can use **`blob_service.list_blobs(<Container Name>, prefix="<Your Prefix>")`**. Below is the code to get the list of blobs for the same.

```py
print("\nList blobs in the container")
generator = blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME, prefix="part-")
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
```

> - download them to a folder locally

To download the blob you can use **`blob_client = blob_service.get_blob_to_path(<Container Name>,<Blob Name>,<File Path>)`**. Below is the code to download the blob as per your requirement.

```py
blob_client = blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME,blob.name,fname)
```

Below is the complete code that worked for us which achieves your requirement.

```py
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<Your_ACCOUNT_NAME>"
ACCOUNT_KEY = "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_KEY>"
CONTAINER_NAME = "<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>"
LOCAL_BLOB_PATH = "C:\\<YOUR_PATH>\\downloadedfiles"

blob_service = BlockBlobService(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_KEY)

# Lists All Blobs which has a prefic of part-
print("\nList blobs in the container")
generator = blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME, prefix="part-")
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
    
# Downloading the blob to a folder
for blob in generator:
    
    # Adds blob name to the path 
    fname = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, blob.name)
    print(f'Downloading {blob.name} to {fname}')

    # Downloading blob into file
    blob_client = blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME,blob.name,fname)
```

**RESULT :**

[image]

Files in my Storage Account

[image]

Files in my Local Folder

[image]

### Updated Answer

```
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

# Lists All Blobs which has a prefic of part-
print("\nList blobs in the container")
generator = blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME, prefix="directory1"+"/"+"part-")
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
    
# Downloading the blob to a folder
for blob in generator:
    
    # Adds blob name to the path 
    fname = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, blob.name)
    print(f'Downloading {blob.name} to {fname}')

    # Downloading blob into file
    blob_client = blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME,blob.name,fname)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SwethaKandikonda-MT, but how would you establish a connection using SAS Token instead of account_name and account_key? That's the only thing I was provided for accessing the blob storage! which looks like this: sas_url = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydir?sv=2020-08-04&si=blobpolicyXYZ&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Comment: @Sal , Sure this is possible but you at least need 2 overloads to achieve this. Please check the attached image https://i.imgur.com/YTG9FyW.png

Comment: thank you, I will try that now. one more thing, you are querying the container name, in my case the files are inside container/directory. how would be best to accommodate that in the code? This was one of the headache points I was not able to bypass and found no documentation on. and yes, I will remember to mark your answer at the end. thank you

Comment: In this case you can just add directory name to prefix (i.e., prefix="directory1"+"/"+"part-") but you need to make sure that a folder with the directory name is present locally. Also, Try checking the updated Answer

Comment: brilliant thank you. I am getting an error importing the library: from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob'
which version of azure.storage.blob are you using?

Comment: @Sal Try using `pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0`

Comment: Thanks @SwethaKandikonda-MT, your code works nicely on a dev env. I spinned up. There is one issue I faced with authorisation on productions env, we can read the files but not list them from a cloud based tool, however I was not able to list nor read the files (using a file name I know exists on production) from the python code. Any idea if a different mechanism/code is need with this level of security, which I am not familiar with at all!? you may have experienced this and know how this works! Many thanks

Comment: will using multi threading cause exceptions such as "permissions denied on file". We have a similar python program and can see this kind of error occuring arbitrarily. We suspect it might be the Threading portion but not sure